# Magento Get list of Orders which contains deleted products

Tags: php, magento-1.9, orders

I want to remove stale data from our Magento store database.
It currently contains orders having products which are deleted from system.
How I can retrieve data for such orders and If required, How I can be able to delete those orders?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to remove the orders for which even a single product/item no more exists:-

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();


foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $item_ids = $order->getAllItems();

    foreach ($item_ids as $item) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

        $product_id = $product->getData('entity_id');

        if (!$product_id) {
            $order->delete();
            remove($order->getId());
        }
    }
}

function remove($order_id) {
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $delete = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $order_table = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_order_grid');
    $invoice_table = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_invoice_grid');
    $shipment_table = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_shipment_grid');
    $creditmemo_table = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_creditmemo_grid');
    $sql = "DELETE FROM  " . $order_table . " WHERE entity_id = " . $order_id . ";";
    $delete->query($sql);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM  " . $invoice_table . " WHERE order_id = " . $order_id . ";";
    $delete->query($sql);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM  " . $shipment_table . " WHERE order_id = " . $order_id . ";";
    $delete->query($sql);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM  " . $creditmemo_table . " WHERE order_id = " . $order_id . ";";
    $delete->query($sql);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I will check it and let you know.. Thanks.. :)